# Issue with mysql backup in cron

Tags: cron, mysql, redhat

I'm just trying to perform a mysqldump and have it scheduled. I'm using RHEL 5 and have added it to the crontab as shown below:

22 13 * * * root mysqldump --user=root --password=12345 mysqldb > /var/backups/mysqldb`date +%d%m`.sql

The .sql file never ended up in the backups folder. I even attempted to run this command line and it worked fine which tells me its something to do with the cron. Furthermore, I added a simple comand like "ls" and the output to the same directory and it worked fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this once but I was more like

> <strike>22 13 * * * mysqldump -u root -p12345 mysqldb >> /var/backups/mysqldb$(date +"%d%m").sql</strike>

there is no root before `mysqldump`. But I am no expert.

BTW, I hope you expect it to run every day at 10:13PM

---

I have tested the above command *does not work*. I suggest you to do this:

1. create a `dbbkp.sh` (I've saved this file in `/home/naishe`)
2. write down the following script, in this shell file

   ```
   mysqldump -u root -pmy_password mysqldb > /home/naishe/mybackup$(date +"%d%m").sql
   ```
3. `chmod a+x dbbkp.sh`
4. Now add this in cronTab

   ```
   51 9 * * * /home/naishe/dbbkp.sh
   ```

I have tested it. It works.

Comment: thanks for the response. i actually tried it without the root as well and didn't seem to make any difference. yes, i only chose 10:13pm as this was the last time i tested the cron job.

Comment: @Aaron You are correct, seems like `date` command is causing issue. I'd suggest go for an independent shell script and call it from Cron. I have updated my answer with the new approach.

Answer (score 0):

I used to support a LAMP server, and we were backuping our databases using this script: http://bash.cyberciti.biz/backup/backup-mysql-database-server-2/ which is linked from this article: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/mysql-backup-script.html

It's easy to adapt and works very well! Just call that in your cron job.