# Cron filename with date is passing Y_m_d not actual date

Tags: mysql, linux, cron, redhat

Using cron to backup mysql to a folder everyday. So tried to schedule cron with below code in linux server. [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578533/daily-database-backup-using-cron-job)

```
0 0 * * * <username> mysqldump -u<mysql username> -p<mysql password> <database name> > /home/<username>/Db_BackUp/expense_$( date +"\℅Y_\℅m_\℅d" ).sql
```

above cron is working but generated file name is like

```
expense_\.Y_\.m_\.d.sql
```

> I need cron to create filename as `expense_2016_04_05.sql`

how to do this in cron?

[related answer from SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565194/issue-with-mysql-backup-in-cron?rq=1)

addition info about cron restart [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193788/restarting-cron-after-changing-crontab-file?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since cron is not a shell, it doesn't execute items in $() wrapper within the cron line in the way a shell does.  However some crons like Vixie Cron will allow you to define variables before your command:

```
YMD=/bin/date +%Y_%m_%d
0 0 * * * /path/to/command > /home/username/Db_BackUp/expense_$($YMD).sql
```

If that doesn't work, you might have to write a helper script and run **it** via cron instead.  For example:

**mysqldump_helper.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
YMD=`/bin/date +%Y_%m_%d`
/path/to/command > /home/username/Db_BackUp/expense_$YMD.sql
```

**crontab**

```
* * * * * /path/to/mysqldump_helper.sh
```

Comment: but i'm using `crontab` from `RHEL7`. do you think it will work?

Comment: You'll just have to try it.  RHEL7 may use "cronie", which may allow the same variable assignment that the first solution above shows.  In any case, however, the second solution will work with any cron program.

Comment: Thanks! @David White anyway i wrote shell script and its working great

Comment: @DavidWhite, Saved me. I was making sure the command that has $(date..) runs in the shell but wondering why it's not running from CRON properly. Now I got it :) Hard lessons for a Windows -> Linux user

Comment: Glad it helped, @JoyGeorgeKunjikkuru !